# Why was the yield keyword introduced for switch expressions? (not just use return keyword)

Tags: java, lambda, switch-expression

> When a return statement occurs within a **lambda expression**, it simply
> causes a return from the lambda. **It does not cause an enclosing method**
> **to return.**

So, for **switch expressions** why the keyword `yield` had introduced while `return` keyword could have been used instead? The first return for returning from method and the inside one for return from switch statement.

```
class TestClass {
    public int testMethod() {
        // ...
        int a = switch (allOptions) {
            case "case1" -> {
                System.out.println("case 1");
                return 1;
            }
            default -> {
                System.out.println("default");
                return -1;
            }
        };

        return a;
    }
}
```

Consider this example for lambda expressions:

```
class TestClass {
    interface FunctionalInterface {
        int test(int n);
    }
    
    public int testMethod() {

        FunctionalInterface f = (n) -> {
            return n * 2;
        };

        return f.test(10);
    }
}
```

### **Is there any special reason for that?**

Why return keyword is confusing in first example and not confusing in the second one?

Comment: Because return always ends the whole method at any point. It would be confusing if it didn't for this special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, when switch expressions were introduced in [JEP 325](https://openjdk.org/jeps/325), it was proposed that `break` should be used to yield a value.

> ```
> int j = switch (day) {
>     case MONDAY  -> 0;
>     case TUESDAY -> 1;
>     default      -> {
>         int k = day.toString().length();
>         int result = f(k);
>         break result;
>     }
> };
> ```

It was changed to `yield` in [JEP 354](https://openjdk.org/jeps/354). It was mentioned that:

> The two statements, `break` (with or without a label) and `yield`, facilitate easy disambiguation between switch statements and switch expressions: a switch statement but not a switch expression can be the target of a `break` statement; and a switch expression but not a switch statement can be the target of a `yield` statement.

Which could be seen as a reason for the change. Using `return` for this certainly would not "facilitate easy disambiguation between switch statements and switch expressions", since you can also `return` in switch statements.

Then, in [JEP 361](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361), it was further explained that overloading `break` was "confusing".

> One aspect of JEP 325 was the overloading of the `break` statement to return a result value from a switch expression. Feedback on JDK 12 suggested that this use of `break` was confusing. In response to the feedback, JEP 354 was created as an evolution of JEP 325.

I would imagine overloading `return` would also be "confusing".

Being able to return from a lambda expression isn't exactly "overloading" `return` in the same sense. The bodies of lambda expressions represent function bodies. It would make sense for `return` to return from functions. The body of a switch expression, isn't a function.

Answer (score 3):

> *"When a return statement occurs within a **lambda expression**, it simply causes a return from the lambda. **It does not cause an enclosing method to return.** ..."*

A *lambda expression* is a *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))*, so it's actually returning from a method, within that scope.

> *"... So, for **switch expressions** why the keyword `yield` had introduced while `return` keyword could have been used instead? ..."*

Using the *return* keyword here would have overlapped its meaning.

It's important to disseminate when you want to simply return from the *switch* and when you want to return from the enclosing method.

A lot of things in *Java* are written out more than logically required, purposely.
An underlying quality of *Java* is that you can read the code as if it were a sentence—similar to *[Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)*.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find it intuitive to use the yield keyword in switch expressions. It helps to distinguish between returning a value from a **method** and returning a value from a **switch expression**.

So, it seems to be a matter of readability and the architect's choice, rather than any functional difference.

Comment: I updated my question and I added an example of lambda expression. What is the difference between these two examples? Why I need yield in first example and I don't need it in the second one?

Comment: @MehdiRahimi In the second example you have a lambda expression, "a lambda expression is a short block of code which takes in parameters and returns a value. Lambda expressions are similar to methods, but they do not need a name and they can be implemented right in the body of a method."

Comment: @MehdiRahimi In other words, a lambda expression "is" a method, and so using `return` in that context is consistent. But ultimately, this was simply a design choice, and so you'd have to ask the language designers why they made the choices they did. Sweeper's answer links to the corresponding JEPs which provide some justification. But note other languages do it differently (see e.g., Kotlin, where `return` in a lambda can be somewhat confusing, and in many contexts simply the last line of code is resolved as the return value of an expression without any `return` keyword).